# Apple notarization error: "The username is not a member of a provider"

Tags: apple-developer, notarize

I've been trying to upload my app for notarization following [Upload Your App to the Notarization Service guide](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/notarizing_macos_software_before_distribution/customizing_the_notarization_workflow#3087734). I codesigned it, created the application-specific password, added it to the keychain. The Developer ID certificate was issued to the account different from the one I used for creating the application-specific password.

Now when I run

```
xcrun altool --notarize-app --primary-bundle-id "com.My.Bundle.Id" --username "myappleid@mail.com" --password "@keychain:MyAppPassword" --file MyApp-1.2.3.dmg
```

it fails saying my account is not a member of a provider:

```
1 package(s) were not uploaded because they had problems:
    /var/folders/c9/0k8wm_mj0g11kvr4kzrksx440000gn/T/63D75020-CC91-437D-BB5F-3AF1F5F3EC3E/com.My.Bundle.Id.itmsp - Error Messages:
        The username myappleid@mail.com is not a member of the provider . Contact your team admin for assistance. (1296)
2019-12-18 20:00:20.497 altool[857:45244] *** Error: The username myappleid@mail.com is not a member of the provider . Contact your team admin for assistance. (1296)
```

I don't really understand what it means. Do I have to subscribe to Apple Developer Program or, otherwise, how do I become "a member of a provider"?

Comment: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/119445

Comment: And https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/113798

Comment: @matt I have already checked those threads, but they don't seem to answer my question

Answer (score 1):

I expect you need the `--asc-provider` argument passed to `altool`. This should be the short string of alphanumerics that represents an account id.